# Is there a more concise way of getting today's date, at a specified time in python

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, timedelta

I need a datetime object whose date is today's date, but whose time is specified (3 am).

I tried this:

```
dt.now().date() + timedelta(hours=3)
```

-> Can't add timedelta to dt.date object

```
foo = dt.now()
foo.hour = 3
foo.minute = 0
foo.second = 0
```

-> Not writable

This works, but seems ugly:

```
foo = dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day, 3,0,0,0)
```

Or, alternatively:

```
foo = dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day) + timedelta(hours=3)
```

Is there a cleaner, more pythonic way of doing this? It feels like 'today at a specific time' should be a fairly common use case...

Comment: `In[1]: dt.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(hours=3)`, `Out[1]: datetime.date(2019, 10, 25)`. no problems with python 3.6.5

Comment: @JHBonarius. The problem is that your result is a date that discarded the time information

Comment: @MadPhysicist true. but no "Can't add timedelta to dt.date object"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) has a classmethod [`now`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now), [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) has a method [`today`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) (which is different form [`datetime.datetime.today`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.today)).

You can use this method along with [`datetime.datetime.combine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) for a reasonably clean solution:

```
_3am = time(3, 0, 0)
dt = datetime.combine(date.today(), _3am)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
foo = dt.datetime.combine(dt.date.today(), dt.time(3))
```